# add an item in kendo grid column

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to add an item in kendo grid's column menu to remove column.

(Success)1.Add an item.
(Success)2.Remove a column.
(Fail)   3.Close Menu after selecting.

I found that other kendo grid's column menu item will close menu after selecting.But my item won't close menu.

I have tried [This(bind select event)](http://dojo.telerik.com/OPATo) And [This(setOptions)](http://dojo.telerik.com/exODiM).
Could anyone give me a hand?

Comment: I have created. And linked it. Can't you see that?
This(bind select event) link to http://dojo.telerik.com/OPATo 
This(setOptions)           link to http://dojo.telerik.com/exODiM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`destroy()`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/menu#methods-destroy) works.

```
menu.bind("select", function (select) {
    grid.hideColumn(field);
    this.destroy();
});
```

[Demo #1](http://dojo.telerik.com/OPATo/2)

```
select:function (select) {
    var menuText = $(select.item).text();

    grid.hideColumn(field);
    this.destroy();
}
```

[Demo #2](http://dojo.telerik.com/exODiM/2)

Comment: @DamienHuang the right way, I think, should be using `close()` method. But who knows why it doens't works in your case. Kendo mysteries.

Answer (score 0):

You can also close the associated popup:

```
var popup = e.container.data().kendoPopup;
menu.bind("select", function (select) {
    grid.hideColumn(field);
    popup.close();
});
```

http://dojo.telerik.com/@Stephen/AKuwuQ